# How to parse a string into f64, and get the remainder of the string, like strtod?

Tags: rust

In C++, `strtod` parses a prefix of a string into a double, and provides the remainder of the string. Example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  char *end;
  double d = strtod("1.5e3randomstuff", &end);
  printf("%g - %s\n", d, end);
}
```

This outputs `1500 - randomstuff`.

How can I achieve the same in Rust? The `str::parse` function errors on invalid characters and does not return the string remainder.

Comment: It looks like a built-in way probably doesn’t exist, even though all the functions in `core::num::dec2flt` are [organized to make it possible](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/num/dec2flt/parse.rs.html#223) (possibly [“for testing”](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/num/dec2flt/mod.rs.html#74)).

Comment: By calling `strtod` directly?  By default rust compiled target is linked to a libc.

Comment: Therr is probably no way to do this with the standard library of Rust. Either search for a crate that does that, call the libc function (it's rather painful) or implement it yourself.

Comment: The fast_float crate, upon which the standard library's implementation is now based, exposes a [`parse_partial`](https://docs.rs/fast-float/latest/fast_float/fn.parse_partial.html) function that you could use.